# Will deportation for drugs be a problem when returning to the US

Tags: passport-stamps, deportation

Deported from Thailand for having possession of 4gms of narcotic. The 
deported person is working in the US, went to Thailand for vacation. Will there be a problem when he goes back to the US? Would this stamp be visible there or anywhere he goes?
Only we close circle know that the case was foisted on him as a result of
an altercation with local police, but non Thais cannot do anything there.

Comment: If US CBP see a deportation stamp they will be bound to ask about it. For non-US citizens they could, potentially, deny entry. Deportation is a red flag for many immigration services. Drugs offences doubly so. Your friend could face an uphill struggle to get visas for some countries.

Comment: @ReddHerring This seems like an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Deportation from Thailand in itself does not make you inadmissible. However, possession of drugs is a criminal offense of moral turpitude which will make you inadmissible. Even if you were not convicted, the standard of proof for admissibility is different.

If you already have a visa, no form asks about deportations from other countries. You don’t need to volunteer information.